# Is there a way to bulk rename hive tables?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, beeline

I want to add a prefix to some hive tables, something like the following:

```
alter table sales_info rename to archived_sales_info;
```

except there's some 200 tables and I'd rather not do them all by hand. Is there any way to do this either via hive itself or perhaps a bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the shell script as below

```
#!/bin/bash

hive -S -e " show tables" > table_list.txt

while read -r line; 
do 

hive -S -e "alter table $line rename to archived_$line;"
echo $line
done < table_list.txt
```

**Before :**

```
    > show tables;
OK
t1
t2
Time taken: 0.016 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

**After executing script :**

```
    > show tables;
OK
archived_t1
archived_t2
Time taken: 0.016 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

Added echo in loop so that you can keep track of which tables has been changed you can redirect it to file also like `echo $line >> changed.txt`

You can do modifications in code as per your requirement. But it should solve your purpose without any changes.

Answer (score 0):

As this is almost certainly a one time thing, considering the following flow:

1. List tables
2. Copy to your favorite editor, for instance excel
3. Use the list of tables to create a list of alter statements

Of course you can also run a script, but this is the fastest I could think of.